# How to prevent a thread to enter in a function if there is already one in?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a function (`my_func`) which can be called by a program that has multiple thread. And I don't want this function to be executed twice or more in the same time. Because I'm writing in memory, and I don't want them to write in the same time.

```
void my_func()
{
    // I want a line that blocks the execution if one is still pending
    /* the code here */
}
```

Comment: Which OS, which threading library?

Comment: Refer here for some samples and explanation https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes

Comment: @hyde Linux, pthread I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mutex lock at the beginning of your function and mutex unlock before going out from your function

```
pthread_mutex_t my_func_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

 void my_func()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&my_func_mutex); // at the beginning of your function
        .....
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_func_mutex); // do not forget to unlock your mutex before going out from your function
    }
```

You can do it in other way if you want:

```
pthread_mutex_t my_func_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
#define MY_FUNC_MACRO() \
    do { \
        pthread_mutex_lock(&my_func_mutex); \
        my_func(); \
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_func_mutex); \
    } while(0)

 void my_func()
    {
        .....
    }
```

and in your code you call `MY_FUNC_MACRO()` instead of `my_func()`

Comment: If the OP doesn't know about mutexes, its a fair bet (s)he also won't know that mutexes need to be unlocked.  Links to posix/windows mutex docs would be nice too.

Comment: @simonc of course, link-only answers are not accepted here eeither.

Comment: @JanDvorak Agreed. Links to man pages often form part of a good answer though and can be particularly useful for beginner questions like this

Comment: Is is possible to block a thread if I don't know it's name (the name of the variable).

Comment: @Elfayer your comment is not clear to me. But if you mean you want to block a thread that you do not knw his name. this is impossible. How you can block something that you do not knwo its id (the name of the thread is the thread id)!?. AND to block  a thread you have to go into the code of the thread and add mutex lock.

Comment: @Elfayer Threads don't get locked, exactly. Mutexes get locked. So a thread can make another thread to wait on a mutex by locking that mutex, but only if that another thread also tries to lock the same mutex while it's locked by the first thread. And thread can try to lock a mutex only if it has that mutex as a variable, but it doesn't need to directly know or care about other threads (if there are any) which may also use the mutex.

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL In fact, `my_func` is a malloc function. So it's in a .so . And it can be called by any program. But I don't want two programs to call my malloc in the same time. It can make problems if I allocate the same memory space for both, for example. So the only thing I can do is wait the end of the execution of the function, if there is one, until it's not finish. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: if there is 2 programs (process)  using your malloc function so do not be worry concerning memory allocation because each process has its own memory space. process could not access or see the memory of other process. Here I m talking about linux programs

Comment: If there is 2 threads using your malloc function then here I advise to use the second definition of macro in your .so library

Comment: threads could shrae the same memory space not like the process

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL Hi, I still have problem with this mutexes ^^. I have `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` in global in file1.c and `extern pthread_mutex_t  mutex;` in file1.h. The thing is that I also call this mutex in file2.c. And that is not working well 9/10 times. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

One method to avoid a collision while writing to same location is to ensure that the writes are done in order. One way to do this is to use a mutex

```
int a = functionThatTakesALongTime();
pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
sum+=a;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
```